# Guardar en un diccionario la información de la ultima fila del dataframe - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Quiero obtener y guardar la última fila de mi dataframe para operar con sus valores, así que pensé en guardarlo en un diccionario.

Hago lo siguiente,

```
val_df = df.iloc[[-1]].to_dict()
print(val_df)
```

El problema es que el diccionario para cada columna guarda el dato (esto genial) pero también el índice (esto me sobra). ¿Hay alguna manera de guardar esta info sin índice?

Sale lo siguiente: `{'id': {1055: 2206931}, 'Dia': {1055: 10}, 'Mes': {1055: 12}, 'Año': {1055: 2019}, 'Hora[UTC]': {1055: 11}, 'Minuto[UTC]': {1055: 13}, 'Segundo[UTC]': {1055: 32}, 'Num secuencia': {1055: 6}}`

Yo querría: `{'id': 2206931, 'Dia': 10, 'Mes': 12, 'Año': 2019, 'Hora[UTC]': 11, 'Minuto[UTC]': 13, 'Segundo[UTC]': 32, 'Num secuencia': 6}`

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Con [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) puedes usar el Con parámetro `orient="records"` el cual debería generar una salida similar a lo que buscas:

```
val_df = df.iloc[[-1]].to_dict(orient="records")
```

Comment: No sé si lo hago mal pero realmente no me la elimina, simplemente la resetea a 0.

Comment: @NEA, ahí edite mi respuesta, creo que es lo que buscas